# can we use datatype of %rowtype , in oracle procedure ,for out parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

```
create or replace 
procedure find_emp_info (
    p_emp_info out emp%rowtype,
    p_empno in emp.empno%type default 7839
) 
is 
p_emp_info emp%rowtype;
begin 
    select *   into emp_info 
    from emp 
    where empno =p_empno;
exception 
when no_data_fount then 
    dbms_output.put_line( 'enter employee number not exists');
when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR OCCURS ') ;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003,SQLCODE||CHR(10)||sqlerrm);
end find_emp_info  ;
/
```

> PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not
>   permitted

why am getting this error in above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors as @Alex mentioned you declare a local the variable `p_emp_info` which can be removed.

The exception you are using is `no_data_fount` which must be `no_data_found`.

```
create or replace 
procedure find_emp_info (
    p_emp_info out emp%rowtype,
    p_empno in emp.empno%type default 7839
) 
is 
begin 
    select *   into p_emp_info 
    from emp 
    where empno =p_empno;
exception 
when no_data_found then 
    dbms_output.put_line( 'enter employee number not exists');
when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR OCCURS ') ;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003,SQLCODE||CHR(10)||sqlerrm);
end find_emp_info  ;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a local variable called `p_emp_info`, but you have an out parameter with the same name.

You don't need that local variable at all; just remove its declaration.

```
create or replace 
procedure find_emp_info (
    p_emp_info out emp%rowtype,
    p_empno in emp.empno%type default 7839
) 
is 
begin 
  select * into emp_info 
  from emp 
...
```